# find rows of R data frame matching condition and create iterable out of tuples

Tags: r, list, parallel-processing

I have an R data frame with two columns. Column `x` is categorical and column `y` is continuous. Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
y <- runif(length(x), 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(x,x)
df_sum <- df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

Think of each categorical value as the ID of a series of some type and y as the values in that series. Eventually I want to be able to compare a selected subset of all possible series using a function `my_func()`.

Firstly I need to identify the "good" tuples and create an interable to use in the second portion of the task.

To find the "good" tuples I need to compare the number of rows for each categorical value of `x` in `df_sum`. I want to find all combinations of categorical values of `x` where the ratio of number of observations is within 0.9 and 1.5.

For example, `x_1=7` and `x_2=5`, and `x_1/x_2=1.4` falls in that range. Thus I want to keep the tuple `(1,2)`.

`my_func(s1,s2)=my_func(s2,s1)`

So I do not need to keep `(2,1)` if I have already `(1,2)`. Once I have all good tuples, I want to iterate through those, and run a function `my_func(s1, s2)` and store `(s1, s2, my_func(s1,s2))` in a data frame.

If good_tuples were a Python-like list `[(1,2),...]` I would write pseudo code like:

```
for tuple in good_tuples:
   s1 <- df[df$x==tuple[0],'y']
   s2 <- df[df$x==tuple[1],'y']
   my_func(s1, s2)
```

Ideally I'd be able to run the loop in parallel with something like mapply.

Comment: The criterion for 'good' tuples sounds ambiguous to me. If `x_1=7` and `x_2=5`, `x_1/x_2 = 1.4`, so the (1,2) tuple is good. But, `x_2/x_1` ~ 0.7, so the (2,1) tuple is bad. If you'd like to still treat the (1,2) tuple as good one, you don't need the criterion `ratio > 0.9` at all.

Comment: You're right. This got lost in translation from the actual data to this made up example. You can pretend that this is a symmetrical range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
z <- melt(tcrossprod(df_sum$count,1/df_sum$count))
#   X1 X2     value
# 1  1  1 1.0000000
# 2  2  1 0.7142857
# 3  3  1 0.2857143
# 4  4  1 1.4285714

pairs <- subset(z[1:2],z$value>1.0 & z$value <= 1.5)
#   X1 X2
# 4  4  1
# 5  1  2

mapply(sum,pairs$X1,pairs$X2) # for example, calculate sum
# [1] 5 3
```

Comment: I'm having problems with mclappy. My function returns multiple values in a list and mclapply start sending a series of warning messages regarding "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length". Should I open a new question?

Comment: Yes, perhaps it is a topic for a different question... But make sure first that you're using `mcmapply`, not `mclapply`!

Comment: Oh... mclapply fixed the problem. Thanks Marat!

Comment: `mcmapply` you meant? )